# Replace the URL in a SharePoint list with a string/link

Tags: url, sharepoint, replace

I want to replace the URL in a SharePoint List with a string/link.

I generated a link column in SharePoint which gets filled by a flow-workflow with the URL to a SharePoint document library, e.g., `https://sharepoint/documents/mydoc`. The workflow works, but in the column the whole URL is displayed. Is there any way to replace the long URL for example with a string link?

Answer (score 0):

Set the field value as `"{URL}", "{Description}"` .

Check [here](http://www.techietaka.com/2017/07/sharepoint-2013-update-hyperlink-field.html) for demo.